# How add two sql queries to one html table

Tags: html, reactjs, html-table

I'm trying to create an application that connects to an MSSQL DB and calls two sql queries on it. It works with the nodeJS backend. And now I try to combine these two results in reactjs into one html table, but I still can't.

I have this code:

```
return (  
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Search in database</h1>

      <div className="form">
      <center>
      <label>Search Data from DB</label></center>
      <input type="text" name="material" />
      <button>Search</button>
      
      
      </div>
      <div class="div-table">
                <thead>
                       
             <div class="div-table-row">
             <div class="div-table-col"><th>Type</th></div>
             <div class="div-table-col"><th>Place</th></div>
             <div class="div-table-col"><th>Free space:</th></div>
             </div>
             
             </thead>
             <tbody>       
            {materialList.recordset.map(value=>{
              return (
                <tbody>
                <div class="div-table-col"><td>{value.MATNR}</td></div>
                <div class="div-table-col"><td>{value.NLPLA}</td></div>

                </tbody>
              )
            })}

                {emptySkate.recordset.map(val=>{
              return (
                  <tbody>
                  <div class="div-table-col"><td></td></div>
                  <div class="div-table-col"><td></td></div>
                  <div class="div-table-col"><td>{val.Line}</td></div>
                                                                
                  </tbody>
              )
                })}
                  
                </tbody>  

        </div>
      </div>
     
  )
```

And result is:

| Type | Place | Free space: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| result query 1 | result query 1 |  |
|  |  | result query2 |

And I would like to have the result like this:

| Type | Place | Free space: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| result query 1 | result query 1 | result query2 |

I tried to change tbody and the table in the table several times, etc. But I still didn't get the result I want, you don't know how to edit the code?

Comment: is there any relation b/w two tables?

Comment: @AmirSaleem No no, the relationship is not there. But I would need to display it in one table.

Comment: Can you combine the queries to a single query with joins or subqueries?

Comment: @lupz That's not possible. The data are completely different and unrelated in the DB structure.

Comment: Why do you use semantic-free `<div>` instead of `<table>`? The `<center>` tag is a leftover from the early 90s. Check out this guide for 21th century centering: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-anything-with-css-align-a-div-text-and-more/

Comment: @lupz Okej, but when i try change it to <table> etc , so i have same problem with result.

Comment: I think it should be possible to merge the recordsets in JS before displaying them.

Comment: you have two diff lists `materialList` and  `emptySkate`.  How are you going to link the rows without any relation? are they in same order? like, Row 1 of `materialList[0]` equals to Row 1 of `emptySkate[0]` ?

Comment: @Cesc You could create a function which takes the two results and spits out a single array, which you render the table with.. is that what you want? You will have to condense both of them to one object or array so you only have to loop once.

Comment: @AmirSaleem Yes, i have two diff list. I don't want to link lines. Last column = result of query 2, not related to the previous two columns. But I want to display it (third column) at the same level - in the same table as the next column.

Comment: @PeterKrebs When it does the result I want, I think that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you can do something like this:

```js
function getRows(materialList, emptySkate) {

 // some assumptions
 // 1. materialList and emptySkate are linked with index. 
 // 2. materialList[0] and emptySkate[0] makes up the first row
 // 3. materialList is the base list, if this is empty, no rows will be returned
 // 4. if emptySkate is empty, the last column will be null or empty

 const result = materialList.map((ml, index) => {
    const es = emptySkate[index] || {};
    return {
       ...ml,
       ...es
    }
 });

 return result;

}
```

Now, in your `tbody` instead of looping over two different arrays, you can loop on the array returned by `getRows` call.

```js
const rows = getRows(materialList.recordset, emptyStake.recordset);
  return (
    <tbody>       
      {rows.map(value=>{
        return (
           <tr>
             -- below markup is just to illustrate
             <div class="div-table-col"><td>{value.MATNR}</td></div>
             <div class="div-table-col"><td>{value.NLPLA}</td></div>
             <div class="div-table-col"><td>{val.Line}</td></div>
           </tr>
       )})}
    </tbody>
  )
```